# How should I represent a contiguous sequence of elements I own?

Tags: c++, idioms, guideline-support-library, std-span

I have a bunch of typed data in consecutive memory that I got as a `T *`; and I also know the number of elements (as a `std::size_t` although it doesn't matter much).

I'd like to use some single type or data structure to represent my stretch of typed data.

Now, what I have is the information for constructing...

- A `gsl::span<T>`, but with ownership.
- A `gsl::owner<T *>`, but with a size.

What type/structure/container would I use to represent all of my information about this data?

Notes:

- Obviously I'm ok with using GSL constructs; stuff in C++2a or Boost is also fine.
- I was thinking of a chimera of `owner` and `span` - perhaps `gsl::owner<gsl::span<T>>`; but I don't really like this idea too much.

Comment: Do you need to dispose of the pointer when done?

Comment: I'm not understanding what you are trying to do.  May be a James Coplien level abuse of the language (assuming you've read Advanced C++).

Comment: @NathanOliver: Either dispose of it, or return an owning pointer, or a unique pointer etc. But in the mean time, I may want to pass the owning-span around to other functions, e.g. as just-a-span.

Comment: @Eljay: Suppose I'm implementing the function `void process_this_data_and_dispose_of_it(T* ptr, size_t length);`

Comment: Second question: Does this have to be a standard/gsl type/container?  If not I'd just fork `span`, call it `owning_span`, and give it a destructor that will clean up the pointer.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Doesn't _have_ to be, but I want to do what other people are doing, if that's at all a common situation to be in.

Comment: `gsl::owner<gsl::span<T>>` fails because owner checks `std::is_pointer` on it's argument

Answer (score 2):

You could inherit `gsl::span<T>` and hold a `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`

```
template <typename T, typename D = std::default_delete<T>>
struct owning_span : public gsl::span<T>
{
    owning_span() {}
    owning_span(T* ptr, index_type size, D d = {}) : span(ptr, size), m_ptr(ptr, std::move(d)) {}
    owning_span(T* first, T* last, D d = {}) : span(first, last), m_ptr(first, std::move(d)) {}
    // other constructors ?
private:
    std::unique_ptr<T[], D> m_ptr;
};
```

One note: you can still copy construct / assign `gsl::span`s from this, slicing off the ownership. Not sure if that is a pro or a con

Comment: Perhaps make the `T*` constructors explicit, and have an implicit constructor taking `owner<T*>` , and one taking a `unique_ptr<T[]>`? Also, method(s) for releasing ownership. But it's not half bad.